# What's the ideal setup for a quick turnaround in Java EE development?

Tags: eclipse, java-ee-6, maven-3, jboss6.x, jboss-weld

I'm currently struggling with the project setup while implementing a Java EE 6 application with Eclipse Indigo and JBoss 6. The application server and the IDE is pretty much set in the project. Maven 3 is used and was the base for the setup by using the WELD archetype and creating a WAR.

Now, the problem is, that I'm very disappointed about the development turnaround. I don't have a working automatic redeploying within eclipse and often need to restart JBoss since it gets confused with the new publishing and then is not able to redeploy correctly. This is very frustrating and time consuming. (Plus I feel the smirks behind me from the guys preferring script languages.)

From earlier projects we were using Seam 2 and the project created by seam-gen came with a somewhat decent republishing, although I still had to do a manual application restart whenever I changed Java classes. Then, from playing around with Netbeans 7 and the integrated GlassFish 3.1 I found that automatic redeployment was working ok. And since Java EE 6 is very wide spread, I assume, there must be a better setup than I have now.

So with this post I hope to get some more insight in having a good project setup for fluent development of Java EE 6 based WAR projects on JBoss and eclipse - who can share some best practices?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found an interesting [article](http://hwellmann.blogspot.com/2011/06/java-ee-6-server-comparison-jboss.html), where the author is basically saying that JBoss 6 within eclipse is not usable - this would be a blunder for me - do others have the same experience or can they show me some light at the end of the tunnel?

Comment: You would be hard pressed to do things quickly in java at the beginning.  I've learned five languages and Java is by far the hardest in terms of the learning curve.  I've spent 2 solid weeks just trying to set up a project, no joke, and I'm still going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use JBoss Tools plugins for Eclipse. [JBoss Tools 3.3M2](http://www.jboss.org/tools/download) is compatible with Indigo and JBoss AS 7 (which is 10 times faster than JBoss 6 for redeploy).

Regarding an equivalent to Seam Gen with CDI, you should really take a look to [Seam Forge](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/SeamForge) which is included in JBoss Tools 3.3 now.

Finally I'm using [Jrebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/) to reload class and configuration without restarting the server. But for now it doesn't work yet with JBoss AS 7, so if you stick with JBoss AS 6 it's a goof combination.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I'll have a look at that for sure. Had a quick test with JBoss 7, it's really fast, but it won't take my deployment artefacts as it, so I have to investigate it further. Speaking of Seam Forge, I heard of it as a base for projects, but how would you use it in eclipse? Also Jrebel I heard of, but since it's commercial, I would prefer another solution.

Comment: JRebel is commercial for sure, but it's the only solution to my knowledge that allows total hot redeployment. If don't want you'll have to restart your server in most of the cases. It's where JBoss AS7 could be a good solution since it's really fast.

I don't understand what you mean with _it won't take my deployment artefacts as it_ could you give me more information ? Anyway you really should use JBoss Tools and it's WTP extension for JBoss AS 7 (JBoss tools 3.3 M2 only), that should solve this issue.

Regarding Seam Forge, it is provided in JBoss tools 3.3 (you have a Seam Forge view).

Comment: I was assuming that I could throw my JAR or WAR artefact into the deploy folder and it would just work, but JBoss was complaining about some class level annotations and I haven't had the time for a deeper look. In seam-gen projects at least they had a mechanism to hotdeploy part of the classes and exchange static files due to an exploded layout, that in conjunction with a fast server startup would suffice. Concerning Forge, I thought I had installed all tools, but Forge was indeed missing. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the answer to your question, but if you want Java and fast turnaround look at http://www.playframework.org/ your script colleagues will be astounded.

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse to work well, use Eclipse Java EE edition and then add the JBoss server adapter.

The usual WTP-tooling then works for automatic deployments etc.

Comment: Do you mean adding a JBoss Runtime in Server view? I did that, but 1) it did not automatically deploy after saving a file like I saw it with Netbeans and GlassFish and 2) after doing a full publish it produced errors about not being able to replace some temp files and the only way to solve it was restarting the server. This experience corresponds with the article mentioned below.